# Webform form results into same form in result page

Tags: forms, blocks, webforms

I am trying to create webform with custom result page. In 'Form settings' page I set Confirmation page and in confirmation message insert my php code.
Here is code:

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') .'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$nid = arg(1); // need to hard-code nid if this is a custom page
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);

$get_type = $submission->data[2]['value'][0];
```

Everithing work fine with this. But also I enabled my form to be block and add it in result page. 
My question is -> Is there any possabilities to show this webform into block with values right before i click submit on main form.